# Display Data in report viewer

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, report, reportviewer

I want to display data in my report using Mysql database, first, I created a datatable using MYSQL command, as below:

```
    public static DataTable getResults(string _reqSelect, string _tableName, int _id_usr)
    {

        string serverIp = "localhost";
        string username = "root";
        string password = "";
        string databaseName = "labo";

        string conString = string.Format("server={0};uid={1};pwd={2};database={3};", serverIp, username, password, databaseName);
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conString);

        DataSet daSet1 = new DataSet();
        DataTable daTable1 = new DataTable();

        try
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd;
            con.Open();
            cmd = new MySqlCommand(_reqSelect, con);
            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt_cre", dt_cre);
            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_societe", _id_societe);

            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            adapter.Fill(daSet1, _tableName);
            daTable1 = daSet1.Tables[_tableName];

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //labo.modele.SYS_LOG_Modele.tracerException(ex, _reqSelect);
        }

        try
        {
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //labo.modele.SYS_LOG_Modele.tracerException(ex);
        }
        return daTable1;

    }
}
```

2 - then I created a dataset, and datatable named "patient" with the same schema as my query:

```
       DataTable dt = getResults("select id,nom,prenom from 
       app_patient","app_patient", 1);
```

3 - the last thing that I did was changing the data source of my report viewer:

```
    //ReportParameter rp = new ReportParameter("ReportParameter1", "test test");
        this.ReportViewer1.Reset();
        this.ReportViewer1.Visible = true;
        this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Report1.rdlc";
        //this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { rp });
        this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dt));
        //this.ReportViewer1.DataBind();
        this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

The datable dt is not empty, I checked the data in it, and I tried it with SQL Server database, and it work perfectly, but I really need to use MYSQL database. I don't know where my problem is, the report viewer keep buffering  but with no result.

Comment: Your datatable doe not have any name.  Do followng :  DataTable daTable1 = new DataTable(_tableName);

Comment: @jdweng already tried it, before and now, and the same problem ;'( ;'(

Comment: All the changes are needed so do not try just one fix.  Did you also try : DataSet daSet1 = new DataSet("DataSet1");  & this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", ds));

Comment: Doesn't work either @jdweng

Comment: I solved it, finally, the case was that I wasn't handling the IsPostBack value, the reportviewer.refresh() generates a postback,
Solution :

if (!IsPostBack)
{
//code of data source and refresh here

}